# megacli is scratching my head

Tags: hardware-raid, raid1, dell-perc

I recently bought an old Dell server from a colleague, he has a PERC H310 mini with four drives.

In this type of things (hardware, raid, disks) I am a newbie and I don't understand more than what I can read on the internet, but megacli is surpassing me.

I don't know how I could have gotten to this (see [32:2] twice times):

```bash
root@desarrollo:~ $ megaclisas-status 
-- Controller information --
-- ID | H/W Model      | RAM    | Temp | BBU    | Firmware     
c0    | PERC H310 Mini | 0MB    | 48C  | Absent | FW: 20.12.0-0004 

-- Array information --
-- ID | Type   |    Size |  Strpsz | Flags | DskCache |   Status |  OS Path | CacheCade |InProgress   
c0u0  | RAID-1 |    930G |   64 KB | RA,WT |  Default |  Optimal | /dev/sda | None      |None         

-- Disk information --
-- ID   | Type | Drive Model                     | Size     | Status          | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | LSI ID  
c0u0p0  | HDD  | ST500NM0011       PA09 Z1M1JWE3 | 465. Gb  | Online, Spun Up | 3.0Gb/s  | 33C  | [32:0]   | 0       
c0u0p1  | HDD  | ST500NM0011       PA09 Z1M1JF1A | 465. Gb  | Online, Spun Up | 3.0Gb/s  | 33C  | [32:1]   | 1       
c0u0p2  | HDD  | ST500NM0011       PA09 Z1M1JYYS | 465. Gb  | Online, Spun Up | 3.0Gb/s  | 32C  | [32:2]   | 2       
c0u0p3  | HDD  | ST500NM0011       PA09 Z1M1JYYS | 465. Gb  | Online, Spun Up | 3.0Gb/s  | 32C  | [32:2]   | 2       

-- Unconfigured Disk information --
-- ID   | Type | Drive Model                     | Size     | Status                        | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | LSI ID | Path    
c0uXpY  | HDD  | ST500NM0011       PA09 Z1M1JFR7 | 465. Gb  | Unconfigured(good), Spun Up   | 3.0Gb/s  | 30C  | [32:3]   | 3      | N/A
```

**I want to remove `c0u0p3` from the raid and add `c0uXpY`.**

Thank you.

---

```
root@desarrollo:~ $ megacli -pdlist -a0
                                     
Adapter #0

Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 0
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 0
WWN: 5000c500640adc23
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221104000000
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JWE3ST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :31C (87.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 1
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 1
WWN: 5000c50063e83a65
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221105000000
Connected Port Number: 3(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JF1AST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :32C (89.60 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 2
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 2
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 2
WWN: 5000c500640ad012
Sequence Number: 3
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Offline
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221106000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JYYSST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :31C (87.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 2
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 2
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 2
WWN: 5000c500640ad012
Sequence Number: 3
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Offline
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221106000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JYYSST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :31C (87.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 3
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 3
WWN: 5000c50063e87754
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221107000000
Connected Port Number: 2(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JFR7ST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :30C (86.00 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




Exit Code: 0x00
```

---

```
root@desarrollo:~ $ megacli -ldpdinfo -a0
                                     
Adapter #0

Number of Virtual Disks: 1
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 930.5 GB
Sector Size         : 512
Mirror Data         : 930.5 GB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 4
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
Default Power Savings Policy: Controller Defined
Current Power Savings Policy: None
Can spin up in 1 minute: Yes
LD has drives that support T10 power conditions: No
LD's IO profile supports MAX power savings with cached writes: No
Bad Blocks Exist: No
Is VD Cached: No
Number of Spans: 1
Span: 0 - Number of PDs: 4

PD: 0 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 0
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 0
WWN: 5000c500640adc23
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221104000000
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JWE3ST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :32C (89.60 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 1 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 1
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 1
WWN: 5000c50063e83a65
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221105000000
Connected Port Number: 3(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JF1AST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :32C (89.60 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 2 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 2
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 2
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 2
WWN: 5000c500640ad012
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221106000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JYYSST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :31C (87.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




PD: 3 Information
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 2
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 2
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 2
WWN: 5000c500640ad012
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 465.761 GB [0x3a386030 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 465.261 GB [0x3a286030 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 465.25 GB [0x3a280000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: PA09
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221106000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             Z1M1JYYSST500NM0011                                 PA09
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :31C (87.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




Exit Code: 0x00
```

Comment: It's `megaclisas-status`,  **not** `megacli`. What you want is certainly possible to do with `megacli` though it has completely different [command line arguments and output](https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161496959/megacli-commands) (and there's a link to a complete manual, worth obtaining and reading). When you have it installed, see `megacli -pdlist -a0` and `megacli -ldpdinfo -a0` and then the command to update RAID could be inferred from that output.

Comment: Also it's possible that this megaclisas-status is just broken and produces the wrong output. I never used it so I can't suggest how to interpret it and what to do based on this. But, I also suspect `[32:2]` can normally appear twice if some SATA port multiplier is connected to card port 2.

Comment: No, their output can not be the same. The `-ldpdinfo` output doesn't include unconfigured disks but includes information on the RAID layout (what are logical disks, what physical disks are in them and which roles they have); `-pdinfo` lists all connected drives but doesn't show anything about their RAID membership. **It looks very strange**, one disk appears twice. I don't understand how it's possible to make it produce such output. Probably somebody cloned hard disk outside of the controller so it is confused? I suggest to **backup all the data** (VD image) and rebuild the array from scratch.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!

Comment: It's not as hard as you might think. Pretty boring task that doesn't require any deep competences (although mildly time consuming — transfer 1 TB back and forth). Dump the image of the RAID VD  (`dd if=/dev/sda of=/temporary/file.img`), recreate the VD, dump the image back. Even bootloader reinstall will not be needed. I suggest doing so, because I suspect something is broken in internal RAID structures and you are at risk losing the data otherwise.

Comment: As I said before, I don't understand. My thing is to be a developer.

Comment: thx @NikitaKipriyanov!

Comment: FYI: I execute from CLI this **megacli -LDRecon -Start -r1 -Add -PhysDrv[32:2,32:2] -l0 -a0** and appear twice times. Pay attention on 32:2 repeated instead 32:2,32:3.